# Not able to display add labels to existing data

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to execute this cell in jupyter but the following error is thrown tried different methods to solve but no use

This is the line that throws error:

data['label'] = data['label'].apply(lambda x:labelling(x))

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3628             try:
-> 3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'label'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_10844\3353650739.py in <module>
     35     return label
     36 
---> 37 data['label'] = data['label'].apply(lambda x:labelling(x))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3503             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506             if is_integer(indexer):
   3507                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3629                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3630             except KeyError as err:
-> 3631                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3632             except TypeError:
   3633                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'label'
```

Comment: your question is incomplete

Comment: Please [do not post images of code or errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) - 
see the answer in the link on why images can hinder others helping you.

Comment: Also post a minimum reproducible example that makes the error. Showing just the error, and the line that makes the error isolated, in this case isn't much help. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please pay attention to the part 'Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.'

Comment: alright I changed it now please take a look at the error and help me solve it